# The variables inside an if block cannot be used outside the block in Haskell, what causes this?

Tags: variables, haskell, scope

And is there any way to fix it so that I can use them outside as well?
Thanks in advance.
I have something like this:

```
if(x==1)
   then
       someList<-aFunction (1,2)
   else
       someList<-aFunction (3,4)


steps involving someList here
```

Comment: It's caused by scoping, and what you can do depends on your code, can we please see some of that?

Comment: I put on the code, but looks like I've got no choice than to put everything inside the if block for separate x's. Thanks

Comment: @DanielFischer ShiDoiSi's answer actually solved my problem :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have misunderstood variables in Haskell: once they are defined, they never change their value, so if you are hoping to do an assignment inside a branch, that won't work. However, maybe the following helps:

```
 let x = if (cond) then .. else .. in f x
```

Be careful not to read `x` in the if-then-else unless you know what you're doing :-) Another reminder: if you use another `let x = ..` inside this construction, it will "shadow" the outer `x`, so it'll effectively be a different, new variable.

Comment: It's a scoping issue, not a re-defining one.

Answer (score 8):

In this particular case,

```
someList <- aFunction (if x == 1 then (1,2) else (3,4))
```

would solve it. Remember that `if ... then ... else ...` is an expression in Haskell.